# Crop an image with special frame

Tags: android, image, image-compression

I am writing an application for android. I need to implement something like below image(From LG's wallpaper selection tool). The original image does not have a circle.

The actual image is cropped to outside rectangle, but thumbnail images are cropped to the inside circle.

I want to implement something like this, but the guide is not a rectangle, but a circle. Is there any examples or library for this?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wanted to implement the same thing, so I modified [edmodo cropper](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper) to have circular selection. Take a look at my library [CircleImageCropper](https://github.com/rachitwatts/CircleImageCropper).

Answer (score 2):

See this library to customize your camera functionality. Hope it works for you.

https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

Answer (score 1):

please use this library:
this library give the circular features..
i already implement circular crop using this library...

https://github.com/MMP-forTour/cropimage

sample code

```
private void cropImage(String imagePath) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CropImage.class);
    Log.d("imagepath", "URI= " + imagePath);
    intent.putExtra("image-path", imagePath);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("circleCrop",true);  //for circular crop
    intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
 }
```

the other also crop image in circle.

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage

https://github.com/dtitov/pickncrop